# Почему не работают субтитры html элемента track в браузере Chrome

Tags: html, html5, видео

Не могу понять, почему не работают субтитры элемента  в Chrome? Хотя в Mozilla работают

```
<video src="video1.mp4" controls width="600" height="300"> 
<track src="newtext.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English" default>
</video>
```

Comment: Вот и у меня такая же ситуация: не подгружаются субтитры из одной и тожей папки с видео на компе. Удалось решить?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте оформить согласно представляемым примерам использования track

```
<video width="600" height="300" autoplay="" controls="">
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2">
    <track label="English subtitles" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="newtext.vtt" default="">
    Your browser does not support the video tag
</video>
```

Comment: Не работает в Chrome

Comment: Просто не показывает? Или пишется, что не поддерживает тэги?

Comment: просто не показывает

Comment: попробуйте указать в src у track полный путь, и у файла на хостинге выставить правда 775

Comment: какой хостинг? у меня на домашнем жестком диске html файл, файл vtt и видеофайл в одной папке.просто запустил html файл в браузере

Answer (score 0):

А ты прописал .vtt-файл? Если нет, то вот пример:

```
    WEBVTT

    00:00.000 --> 00:20.000
      Титр1
    00:40.400 --> 02:00.000
      Титр1
```

И так далее...
00:20.000 это: 00 минут, 20 секунд, 000 миллисекунд